# Handling errors in angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I am trying to handle errors in angular. Not sure where exactly it should be handled, but I tried to do it in service.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CaseListService {
  public constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  private get baseUrl() {
    return environment.apiBaseUrl || '/api';
  }

  public getCaseList(): Observable<CaseListModel[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + '/cases').pipe(
      map((response) => response as Array<CaseListModel>),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err.status) {
          console.log('Service temporarily unavailable' + err.status);
          this.router.navigate(['/unavailable']);
        }
        return throwError(err.statusText);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my `component.ts` where I am calling the service:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-case-list',
  templateUrl: './case-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./case-list.component.css'],
})
export class CaseListComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'List of cases';
  readonly CaseList$: Observable<CaseListModel[]>;

  constructor(private caseListService: CaseListService) {
    this.CaseList$ = caseListService.getCaseList();
  }

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['ID', 'name', 'actions'];
  dataSource = this.caseListService.getCaseList();

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

I disabled backend and tried it. Result is just frontend with empty data. Redirect fails, console log shows nothing too. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse#description) on http client error handling.

As you can see the status field of HttpErrorResponse is optional, meaning it could be undefined. This will explain why the `console.log` and `navigate` are not invoked.

Comment: Yeah removing if really helps thanks morty.